# Singularities and Residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

[image]

For part (a) the singularity is 1/root2 + i/root2 ? 
And it is a pole of order 1?

I am having trouble calculating the residue

So far I have:

residue = limit (as z tends to 1/root2 + i/root2) of (1/root2 + i/root2)/(1+z^4)

But I do now know how to compute this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$z^4=-1=e^{\pi i\left(1+2k\right)}\;,\;\;k=0,1,2,3\implies z_k=e^{\frac{\pi i}4(1+2k)}$$

thus in the first quadrant we have only one (simple) pole:

$$z_0=e^{\pi i/4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)$$

The residue here is

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)\frac1{z^4+1}\stackrel{l'Hospital}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac1{4z^3}=\frac1{4e^{3\pi i/4}}=\frac14\frac{\sqrt2}{1-i}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\frac{1+i}2=\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}(1+i)$$

Comment: when i do e^(i3pi/4) i get -(sqrt2)/2 + (isqrt2)/2 and so end up with -(1+i)/4sqrt(2), what am i doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: First, you have twice $\;i\;$ i nthe exponent, I don't know why. Second, I don't understand what you write so well since you use no proper format, but never mind: what is **not** clear in my answer? If everything's clear then you're wrong, otherwise I might be wrong.